# speeding up this vba script

Tags: vba, performance, excel

Upon opening this workbook the following script runs which writes a formula to create a link to multiple workbooks. Each workbook writes to 3 columns i.e. workbook 1 writes to A, B and C and workbook 2 writes to D, E, F etc..

```
WBNAME = "=IF(AND('\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]iForms'!A2<>"""",'\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]iForms'!E2=""""),'\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]iForms'!A2,"""")"
Worksheets("All Release Items").Range("A2:A100").Value = WBNAME
WBNAME2 = "=IF(AND('\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]iForms'!A2<>"""",'\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]iForms'!D2<>"""",'\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]iForms'!E2=""""),'\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]iForms'!D2,"""")"
Worksheets("All Release Items").Range("B2:B100").Value = WBNAME2
WBNAME3 = "=IF('\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]All Release Items'!A2<>"""",'\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\Release Note\[Aliens.xlsm]All Release Items'!A1,"""")"
Worksheets("All Release Items").Range("C2:C100").Value = WBNAME3
```

There are currently 12 workbooks all .xlsm and located within the same file path.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is it needs to update the formulas to referenced workbooks that aren't open in the application session. It will probably go faster if the workbooks are opened, then the formulas are entered.

You can test this by setting your calculation mode to manual (in the "Calculation" section of the "Formulas" ribbon page, or `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`), then running the macro, then "Calculate Now" (on the ribbon again, or F9), and see how long that takes. Compare the times running it like that when the referenced workbooks are open vs closed. I think you'll find the macro takes a short amount of time to add the formulas, but the calculation takes a long time because the workbooks are closed.

If that's the case, rewrite it to open the workbooks before calculating.

Also, you might want to consider putting your data in a database if it needs to be referenced like that.